# How can I combine a rotation and drawing function to draw a circular spoke pattern?

Tags: graphics, f#

My assignment:

> Using rotation function, rot and graphics primitive function, toTree make a program, which calls render to draw 36 spokes on the screen as illustrated in Figure 2

[image: 36 Spokes]

The rotation function is given by:

```
type vec = float * float

let rot (v1: vec) (k: float)=
     ((cos(k) * fst v1))+((snd v1 * (-sin(k)))), (fst v1 * sin(k) + (snd v1 * cos(k)))

let (v1:vec) = (3,10)
let (k:float) = 3.2

let result = rot v1 k
printfn "%A roteres så den bliver %A" v1 result
```

And my graphics function uses the [Diku Canvas](https://diku-dk.github.io/diku-canvas/reference/global-canvas.html) library and is given by:

```
#r "nuget:DIKU.Canvas, 2.0"
open Canvas
open Color

type vec = float*float

let w,h = 400, 400
let toTree (c: color) (v10: vec) : PrimitiveTree 
    = piecewiseAffine c 2 [(0.0, 0.0); (fst v10, snd v10)]

let tree = toTree gold (20.0, 20.0)
let draw = make tree

render "Vector" w h draw
```

My problem here is:

1. I don't really have any idea how to combine the two functions.. I can't seem to find anything in the
   literature nor our lectures.
2. I'm also having some trouble just to imagine which list of coordinates i need to create that 36 spokes image.

Comment: I think the goal with the rotate function is that you don't have to figure out the coordinates yourself. Do you know what the `toTree` function is doing?

Comment: @GeneralGrievance the ```toTree``` function takes a color, c, and a vector, v, and returns a graphic primitive representing a vector which its tail in (0.0,0.0).

Because of this i'm still having some trouble. I dont feel like this is giving me a lot of information.

Comment: `toTree` is sufficient to draw one spoke. The first coordinate is at (0, 0), the center, the second is a coordinate (vector) of your choosing. I don't have an IDE, so I can't completely do everything, but here's an [example program](https://tio.run/##fU9BCsJADLz3FYMgZNXGrbWiQgXv/kA8SG2hVLeluxYF/15TF/RmDkmYmWSSwoZZ3eZ9755Nji7PkKK41meHia9BcM0d2tqBumg7KBSo2npSpQEkiLLaUqWGGevQRUpNiay5SCsYhbY0QkvMQF4hsAcxxU/p1yjlTQfDj18KWmieQbMwR82aOU5Yn/Bxf@1wKK3j27mR7XeDB8KdpAlijpZRslmskjhZb9aYI16xVn@mhj/lksdX07SlcYXBaLwf9f0b "F# (.NET Core) – Try It Online").